# TCP/IP polling client send and recv in c

Tags: c, unix, networking, tcp, chat

I am making a Chat server and client using tcp/ip in c. I made the server part which threads multiple clients. On client side I have a while loop that can send a line and then wait for the server reply. I want to make client poll both send and recv functions to check if the another client has sent something. This is what I have -

```
while (1){
    char buffer[BUFLEN];
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);
    gets(buffer);
    //sendall(sd, buffer, BUFLEN);
    send(sd, buffer, BUFLEN, 0);
    printf("sent:%s\n",buffer);
    //recvline(sd, buffer, BUFLEN);
    recv(sd, buffer, BUFLEN, 0);
    printf("recieved:%s\n", buffer);
}
```

How do I poll both send() and recv() at the same time and execute the one that comes first??

Want to do something like this..

```
if(send(sd, buffer, BUFLEN, 0) == true)
   send something
else if(recv(sd, buffer, BUFLEN, 0) == true)
   receive something
```

Comment: You're probably looking for the [`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) function to *multiplex* between the read and write file descriptors.

Comment: How would that work? Can you explain?

Comment: Dont assume send() or recv() to process the number of characters you gave them in the 3rd argument;  use the return value instead.

Comment: And regarding [select()-based services](http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html) check there. (and a million other places)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like `select` ([MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)).

The basics of using it are as follows:

- Load up `fd_set` structs with the socket handles you want to check. Load one `fd_set` with sockets you want to check for new data to receive, one with sockets you want to send on, and optionally, one with sockets you want to check for errors.
- Call `select`, passing it pointers to your `fd_set` structs.
- When `select` returns, the set you passed as the second parameter (`readfds`) only contains the sockets you passed it which have data waiting. You can call `recv` on them and it will return immediately. The set you passed as the third parameter (`writefds`) contains sockets which are ready for writing. You can call `send` on them and it will return immediately.

Comment: Select is awful. Platforms provide way better mechanisms these days. For example, kqueue, epoll, etc. If you intend on giving platform-independent answers, the best way is probably to recommend a library like `libevent`...

Comment: That's correct. And there are good mechanisms for that, and select is not one of them. Yes, `select` would work, but recommending `select` today is like recommending Flintstones mobile to someone who is looking for a Lamborghini.

Comment: I beg to differ, there is nothing wrong with select or poll. *there are platforms*: please elaborate.

Comment: @VladLazarenko Thanks for the info. Since I'm not very experienced in the area, what makes `libevent`/`epoll`/`kqueue` faster?

Comment: @slavik262: For example, no need for linear search. On top of that, they are native to the OS, thus less "glue" levels are needed for the functionality to work. Those mechanisms are also more advanced and support more features. For example, with epoll one can asynchronously handle POSIX signals in a safe and sound manner.